# Bootstrap row scrollable in IE8

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-8

This is a addition to the answer posted in [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20332830/bootstrap-3-horizontal-scrollable-row-website-design/24764216#24764216)
It works perfectly in modern browsers but not in IE8. I researched about it and some posts suggested to include respond.js in addition to bootstrap.js. But still no luck. Thanks,

Comment: Is bootstrap.css being hosted by the same domain as respond.js?

Comment: Yes it is ... i have all the css and js locally. The order is bootstrap.css, then my.css (that has the style in the post that i linked), bootstrap.js and finally respond.src.js

Comment: Are you running a web server locally or just opening it straight in your web browser?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a CDN for Bootstrap CSS and use Respond.js (has to be local) without a proxy page work-around.

From my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24205508/respond-js-with-external-css-resources/24226056#24226056):

See https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond#cdnx-domain-setup and check out the cross-domain example at https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond/tree/master/cross-domain

```
<!-- Respond.js proxy on external server -->
<link href="http://externalcdn.com/respond-proxy.html" id="respond-proxy" rel="respond-proxy" />

<!-- Respond.js redirect location on local server -->
<link href="/path/to/respond.proxy.gif" id="respond-redirect" rel="respond-redirect" />

<!-- Respond.js proxy script on local server -->
<script src="/path/to/respond.proxy.js"></script>
```

Also, load order is important. You need to have declare Respond.js after your CSS has loaded, otherwise it doesn't know what to correct.

Comment: You were right. I had to load the load the css before. now the issue is that it creates a lot of white space between the columns.

Comment: That's cause you overwrote your width of your container to be 100%. I would suggest using `container-fluid` on full-width containers (it's already a part of bootstrap) then a fixed width `container` (with a `row` inside if you have columns nested). That way the columns are proportionate to the container size rather than the monitor screen.